# Excel count unique occurrences of a text entry based on a status contained in a seperate column

Tags: excel, distinct

Alright, this is driving me insane...

I have a section of data in a spreadsheet that looks like this:

```
Column A                 Column B        Column C

lksdf-46-we-32           Fire                 1
lksdf-46-we-32           Fire                 2
lksdf-46-we-32           Fire                 3
lksdf-46-we-32           Fire                 4
wgw3f-18-bw-11           Ice                  1
wgw3f-18-bw-11           Ice                  2
wgw3f-18-bw-11           Ice                  3
wgw3f-18-bw-11           Ice                  4
possf-12-he-91           Fire                 1
possf-12-he-91           Fire                 2
possf-12-he-91           Fire                 3
possf-12-he-91           Fire                 4
oiwen-20-lw-93           Water                1
oiwen-20-lw-93           Water                2
oiwen-20-lw-93           Water                3
oiwen-20-lw-93           Water                4
```

In another spreadsheet, named 'Variables', I have a lookup category that looks something like this:
Column A
Fire
Water

I need to find the number of distinct entries in column A of the raw data sheet where column B matches any entry in column A of the Variables sheet.  What I'm looking for is an excel formula, but everything I've tried either returns duplicates (as a starting point) or returns 0.  Also, could you please explain in detail how the query works in excel?  I'm a fairly experienced programmer, but I'm having a heck of a time wrapping my head around these functions in excel that I've been tasked to finish by the end of the day.

Comment: Could you try formatting that column data please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this "array formula" somewhere in the raw data sheet

`=SUM(IF(FREQUENCY(IF(ISNUMBER(MATCH(B2:B100,Variables!A:A,0)),IF(A2:A100<>"",MATCH(A2:A100,A2:A100,0))),ROW(A2:A100)-ROW(A2)+1),1))`

confirmed with <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd>

The formula uses `FREQUENCY` function, with the "bins" being the row numbers, and counts bins that have 1 or more entry. Entries are only made when the column B item matches Variables column A.....and the second `MATCH` function ensures that the same row number (the first match) is entered for each repeated item in column A, which guarantees that duplicates are not counted

This formula looks at 100 rows of data in raw data sheet, increase as required but note that formula is very "expensive" so may prove impractical with very large datasets

Comment: You know, I figured I wouldn't get an answer because I didn't format the columns...didn't have the time to.  I came up with the same answer and upon coming back here and realizing that you were correct, I wanted to give you credit.  

Thanks for the prompt answer!